# What are the different purposes of "id" and "name" for shapes in Konva

Tags: konva

Konva shapes have both "id" and "name" properties. Presumably these are intended to serve different needs, but how should they be used in Konva? Are either used by Konva itself, or are they just holders for user-defined data?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found elsewhere in documentation:
id is meant to be unique (like HTML id)
name is multi-valued like HTML class
Both are user defined.